# Could ChainLink facilitate getting the current Ask/Bid price from DEX?

Tags: solidity, chainlink

Could ChainLink facilitate getting the current Ask/Bid price from DEX
like Binance and PancakeSwap?

"bidPrice" and "askPrice" on Binance
https://github.com/binance/binance-spot-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md#new-order--trade

"price" on PancakeSwap
https://github.com/pancakeswap/pancake-info-api/blob/develop/v2-documentation.md

Could you show an example of how to do this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If the data is accessible via an API then you can use [Chainlink Any-API](https://docs.chain.link/docs/make-a-http-get-request/) calls to bring it into your smart contract

To do so, you need to know 3 things

1. The API endpoint that contains the data, and the inputs required
2. The outputs that the API returns, including their types (integer, string etc), as well as the path in the resulting JSON that contains the data you want
3. A Chainlink oracle on the network you're contract is on that has a compatible job that you can use (whether one you run yourself or someone elses)

Once you have these things, you can use the example consumer contract in the docs linked above, and then change the values to suit. ie here is an example contract that will make an API call to PancakeSwap to get the price of PancakeSwap token on BSC testnet:

1 - API address and inputs. In this case, according to your linked docs, the URL of the API call is `https://api.pancakeswap.info/api/v2/tokens/0x0E09FaBB73Bd3Ade0a17ECC321fD13a19e81cE82`. The only input required is the token address in the URL

2 - We want the price, which is an integer and in the 'price' JSON element. We will multiply the price by 10**8 when we bring it on-chain because Solidity can't handle decimals

3 - Because this is a simple API call, we can use a community run CL node that takes a HTTP GET request, parses the JSON to find an element we specify, then multiplies the result and converts it to the type we want before returning it on-chain. Taking a look at the [BSC testnet jobs on market.link](https://market.link/search/jobs?hierarchicalMenu%5BhierarchicalCategories.lvl0%5D=Binance&sortBy=job_created_at_desc), I found a suitable one [here](https://market.link/jobs/c314932c-2ee7-449b-b9f7-c2ba8fcf0ad2) (GET, multiples result, returns a uint). From here we take the job ID and the oracle address, and note the cost in LINK required to use it

Now that we have all these details, we can modify the standard API consumer contract and put them all in, as follows. Changes I made include updating variables to reflect price instead of volume, also i changed the variables for job, oracle contract and fee, and i changed the setPublicChainlinkToken() method in the contructor to setChainlinkToken, specifically passing in the address of the [LINK token on BSC testnet](https://docs.chain.link/docs/link-token-contracts/)

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/ChainlinkClient.sol";

contract APIConsumer is ChainlinkClient {
    using Chainlink for Chainlink.Request;
  
    uint256 public price;
    
    address private oracle;
    bytes32 private jobId;
    uint256 private fee;
    

    constructor() {
        setChainlinkToken(0x84b9B910527Ad5C03A9Ca831909E21e236EA7b06);
        oracle = 0x19f7f3bF88CB208B0C422CC2b8E2bd23ee461DD1;
        jobId = "9b32442f55d74362b26c608c6e9bb80c";
        fee = 0.0001 * 10 ** 18; // (Varies by network and job)
    }
    
    function requestPriceData() public returns (bytes32 requestId) 
    {
        Chainlink.Request memory request = buildChainlinkRequest(jobId, address(this), this.fulfill.selector);
        request.add("get", "https://api.pancakeswap.info/api/v2/tokens/0x0E09FaBB73Bd3Ade0a17ECC321fD13a19e81cE82");
        request.add("path", "price");
        
        // Multiply the result by 1000000000000000000 to remove decimals
        int timesAmount = 10**18;
        request.addInt("times", timesAmount);
        
        // Sends the request
        return sendChainlinkRequestTo(oracle, request, fee);
    }
    
    function fulfill(bytes32 _requestId, uint256 _price) public recordChainlinkFulfillment(_requestId)
    {
        price = _price;
    }


}
```

Once you compile and deploy, you then need to fund the contract with enough link to perform the request. You can get some testnet BSC LINK from the [faucet](https://faucets.chain.link/), then transfer enough from your wallet to the deployed contract (in this case 0.001 LINK)

Once that's done you can execute the requestPriceData function, wait 30 secs then check the price getter function to see if you have a result. If you don't have a result after a while (1 min), it could mean the BSC node isn't up still. You can either run your own node, or use another network like Ethereum Kovan or Polygon Mumbai, which has [many more active jobs](https://market.link/search/jobs?hierarchicalMenu%5BhierarchicalCategories.lvl0%5D=Ethereum%20%3E%20Kovan)

Comment: Output is 0.
I waited to no avail. Tried Kovan too. 
I believe PancakeSwap returns the value as a String and not Uint.
The JSON path is x.data.price.
How would you edit the code to get the price of the token as a String?

Comment: Could it be that the oracle address is offline?
https://market.link/jobs/c314932c-2ee7-449b-b9f7-c2ba8fcf0ad2
I deploy and requestPriceData numerous times and the latest transaction is still 139 days 15 hrs ago.